# Rmarkdown - .rmd file still caching even if cache= FALSE?

Tags: knitr, r-markdown

I am building a website in Rmarkdown. One of the .rmd files I am using loads some elements of its content from a table that is created when the user clicks on a link to the .rmd document. 
The reason why I have chosen this approach is that I want to use a single .rmd file to make the page layout, but re-creating parts of the content every time, by loading elements on the basis of which link object the user clicks on.
However, when the user clicks on more than one link in the same session, the page from the .rmd document always shows the content from the very first link clicked. I am guessing this is a caching problem, although it does not change if I set `opts_chunk$set(cache=FALSE)`. I have also tried `opts_chunk$set(cache.extra=file.info("~/subset_table.csv")$mtime)` as suggested [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/238) , but it also does not work.

**NB**: I am running the documents from RStudio, at the moment. I am not sure if the issue has to do with the .rmd document being called from the same RStudio session in the same run of the index.rmd document.

Below is the code.

- I am using rows in a shiny app DT table as links:

  ```
  ui<- fluidpage(

   sidebarPanel(textInput("type",label = "type", value = ""),

   mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput("res")),

   conditionalPanel(
     condition="output.res",
     DT::dataTableOutput("tableSubset")
   )

  )


  server<- function(input,output, data= dt) {

   res.table=subset(dt,dt$Type=input$type)
   res.table=as.data.frame(res.table)
   colnames(res.table)=c("Name","Type","Value")

   output$res=DT::renderDataTable( {      
     res=res.table
     return(res)
   }, selection=single, server=T)

   output$tableSubset=DT::renderDataTable({

     rown=input$res_rows_selected
     if (length(rown)) {

       fullTable=res.table
       name=fullTable[rown,"Name"]

       tableSubset= subset(dt,dt$ID==name)
       write.csv(tableSubset,"~/subset_table.csv")
       datatable(tableSubset,callback=JS("onclick=window.open('/page.rmd','_blank')"))
    }

   })
  }

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
  ```
- This is the Rmarkdown document:

  ````
  output: html_document
  _ _ _ _ 

  ``` {r setup, include=FALSE}
  knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache=FALSE)
  ```

  ```{r contentLoader}
  myTable=read.csv("~/subset_table.csv", header=T)

  name=as.character(rnaTable$ID)
  ```


  ##  `r name `
  ````